# enable pinch to zoom on image tag

Tags: nativescript

i would like to enable pinch to zoom on an image, i load the image source passing in the context from the previous view, i tried a plugin, https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-image-zoom, but it has a strange behaviour, when i come from another page it shows the previous image, and so for the next pages. So i thinked if there is a way to "enable" the event pinch zomm and pan directly on the tag img, 
here is my code, i use pure js, in this version i have just the img tag inside the page content, but it should be a GridLayout or a StackLayout, or a plugin tag, anyoune could help me?

```
<Page loaded="loaded" xmlns:shared="shared" xmlns:nsDrawer="nativescript-ui-sidedrawer" xmlns:ui="nativescript-image-zoom"
>
    <shared:actionbar></shared:actionbar>
    <nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer" showOverNavigation="true">
        <nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
            <shared:side-drawer></shared:side-drawer>
        </nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
        <nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>

                <Image src="{{ img }}"/>

        </nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    </nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer>
</Page>
```

```
let Observable = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable").Observable;
let moment = require('moment')
let LoadingIndicator = require("@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator").LoadingIndicator;
let loader = new LoadingIndicator();

moment.locale('it');

let pageData = new Observable();
let page;
let gotData;
exports.loaded = function (args) {
    loader.show();
    page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
    gotData = page.page.navigationContext;
    pageData.set("img", gotData.event.pictureUrl);
    loader.hide()
};
```

Comment: Doing everything on your own could be overhead. If you have issues with plugin, please explain the issue / what you mean by previous image? Can you share a sample project?

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, i asked also on the github of the plugin i used. for the previous image i mean the previous image that i set as src of the image, i have a page with many items, each one navigate to this and load a different image by setting it in the src. well it's like a caching issue, at the load of the image i see the one that should be the previous. sorry but i can't give an example project

Comment: Cache issues are quite common with remote images, it can be solved generally with some tweaks on how you handle urls. Perhaps you could download the image and give a local path to plugin.